# Finding peaks within a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, bioinformatics

I am trying to analyse some biological data within R. I have a data frame that contains a window for positions on a dna sequence that I want to analyse. For example, 237-1437. I have a count of files which contains the position and a count. For each window, I want to analyse each position in the count file and look for significant peaks in counts. Does anyone know how to do this?

The count file looks like this and is within a data frame labelled `df2`:

```
V1    V2    V3   
gene  1     6
gene  2     0
gene  3     0
gene  4     10
....
```

The data frame which contains the window looks like this and is labelled `df`:

```
seqnames    start    end    strand   window_end   
gene        65       1237   +        1437
gene        1262     2134   +        2334
gene        2178     4511   +        4711
```

I want the output to produce a list of significant peaks.

Comment: When do you call a peak significant? If you are referring to "statistical significance", you would have to say what your null hypothesis is and what your significance test is.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "finding peaks", statistically that means finding outliers in the data, or finding minimum and maximum numbers to help you investigate further and analyse these peak values.

**Using Statistical Summary:**

If you're interested in a specific column, let's say from your data frame `df` column `V3`, then in base R you can do the following:

```
summary(df$V3)
```

This would result in six statistical values in your data: minimum value, first quantile, median, mean, third quantile, and maximum value. Also, you can store the values in a vector and use the values for further analyses by using the index of each value in the summary.

**Visualisation of the above along with outliers:**
In addition to printing these values, you can plot them in R using `boxplot` function; this would show you the outliers or the peaks with circles.

```
boxplot(df$V3)
```

**Demo:**

```
#generating df with additional random data to be able to plot and show outliers:
df = data.frame(V1 = rep("gene", 10), 
                V2 = 1:10, 
                V3 = c(6,0,0,10,50, 20, 5, 7, 9, 100))

df
```

Result:

```
     V1 V2  v3
1  gene  1   6
2  gene  2   0
3  gene  3   0
4  gene  4  10
5  gene  5  50
6  gene  6  20
7  gene  7   5
8  gene  8   7
9  gene  9   9
10 gene 10 100
```

The statistical summary:

```
summary(df$V3)
```

Result:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    5.25    8.00   20.70   17.50  100.00
```

The boxplot:

```
boxplot(df$v3, ylab = "V3", main = "Boxplot")
```

Resultant plot:

[image]

***EDIT: (16/02/2023)***

**Plotting each numerical column in the data frame:**

To plot each numerical column in the data frame in a box plot, we can use `for` loop to loop through the data frame's columns and exclude the character-class column. Since we know that its index is 1, then we can begin our loop at 2, as shown below:

```
#Updated data frame with addition numeric columns: 
df2 = data.frame(V1 = rep("gene", 10), 
                V2 = 1:10, 
                V3 = c(6,0,0,10,50, 20, 5, 7, 9, 100), 
                V4 = c(1000, 1269, 9000, 6984, 1253, 5555, 7845, 1254, 7000, 3365))
```

```
> df2
     V1 V2  V3   V4
1  gene  1   6 1000
2  gene  2   0 1269
3  gene  3   0 9000
4  gene  4  10 6984
5  gene  5  50 1253
6  gene  6  20 5555
7  gene  7   5 7845
8  gene  8   7 1254
9  gene  9   9 7000
10 gene 10 100 3365
```

```
for(i in 2:length(df2)){
  print(paste(colnames(df2[i]), "--", summary(df2[i]), sep = " "))
  if(min(df2[i]) != max(df2[i])){
    boxplot(df2[i], xlab = colnames(df2[i]), ylab = colnames(df2[i]))
  }
}
```

Resulting plots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I am wanting to look at each position in df2 which is within the windows in df. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @margo I've just updated the answer to include a for loop to plot each position/column in df2. I hope this helps.